# Invalid application's package name in 'AndroidManifest.xml React native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to set up the app for the play store and I change the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml file. While making the app build I am getting a warning. I try to find the solution but did not get the right answer.

> warn Invalid application's package name "com.bilalyaqoob.Animals" in 'AndroidManifest.xml'.

**bilalyaqoob** is my name and **Animals** is app name.

Can you please me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must changes all package name.

If you use Visual Code you can do this.

[image]